# How can I select other table fields when using GROUP BY and MAX?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table named Orders and fields CustomerId, EmployeeId, OrderDate

I want to select all those fields for each CustomerId by the latest OrderDate.

So far, I've managed to select CustomerId and OrderDate, but I don't know how to include EmployeeId

```
 SELECT [CustomerId], MAX(OrderDate)
      FROM [Orders] 
      GROUP BY [CustomerId]
      ORDER BY [CustomerId]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by orderdate desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

That is the "traditional" solution.  If you have a list of all customers, I like the solution using `cross apply`:

```
select o.*
from customers c cross apply
     (select top 1 o.*
      from orders o
      where o.customerid = c.customerid
      order by o.orderdate desc
     ) o;
```

Comment: almost...needs to be ordered by orderdate DESC